# If I assign .URL to IE as a default program in Windows 10, how can I assign it back to Edge, if I change my mind later?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

The Current Default is set to Internet Browser. When I open Change Program, Internet Browser is shown first and I'm able to choose IE from a list. What is the path to MS Edge, if I want to revert?

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft Edge` is located in the following directory:

> C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe

This directory might change as new builds of Windows 10 are released.  So an alternative solution is to locate the current location of `MicrosoftEdge.exe` by doing a search.

Comment: Is MicrosoftEdge.exe inside the scope of %PATH?

Comment: I don't know what your PATH variable is, feel free to check, I provided the location of the folder it is currently in.  Of course I am a little confused why you are asking if its contained within the PATH variable.

Comment: It makes finding it trivial if its location changes.

Comment: I can only answer the proposed question.